# Symfony4. Force change password. Redirect to change-password site

Tags: security, authentication, symfony4

I build login logic myself and i don't want use FosUserBundle.

I check Entity User date of last change password and if is more than 30 days i want that user will not fully authenticated only redirect to sites that they will must change password.

I try to use SecurityListener and onSecurityInteractiveLogin method.
Checking date works, but user is authenticated and redirect to sites what i configured in case after correct login (not to route change-password).

```
class SecurityListener
{
    private $tokenStorage;
    private $em;
    private $session;
    private $urlGenerator;

    public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage, EntityManager $doctrine, Session $session, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->em = $doctrine;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
    }

    /**
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $lastPasswordAt = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()->getlastPasswordAt();
        $data = new \DateTime("now");
        $data->modify('-30 days');

        if ($lastPasswordAt < $data) {
            $this->session->invalidate();
            return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_change_password');
        }
    }
}
```

Please give me some hints how to handle this issue.